# sql getting values from the same table and same column into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

There are two tables; **X_User_Role** and **Role** like this

X_User_Role table:

```
************************
UserRoleID UserID RoleID
************************
1           1      1
************************
2           1      2
************************
3           2      1
```

Role table:

```
********************************
RoleID  Name         SecondaryFl
********************************
1       PrimaryRole    0
********************************
2       SecondaryRole  1      
********************************
```

Now I am writing a select statement with joins so that in my final output it should come as (considering only 1 user ID) :

```
UserID     PrimaryRoleName      SecondaryRoleName
***********************************************************
  1         PrimaryRole          SecondaryRole
```

I have tried joining like this:

```
select xur.UserID, r1.Name as PrimaryRoleName, r2.Name as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role xur 
JOIN Role r1
ON r1.RoleID = xur.RoleID
JOIN Role r2
ON r2.RoleID = r1.RoleID AND SecondaryFl = 1
```

But I always get output like this:

```
UserID     PrimaryRoleName      SecondaryRoleName
***********************************************************
  1         PrimaryRole          PrimaryRole
```

I have tried different variations of the above joins but I never get the desired output. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am a complete novice at SQL. Can anyone please assist?

**Note:** I have to use JOINS because this is a part of a bigger select which is entirely made up of JOINS.

Comment: Don't you think you might need to specify on the first join that `SecondaryFl <> 1`?   And make your second join to the `xur` table, not the `r1`

Comment: I tried that as well. In that case also I am getting both Primary and Secondary roles value as 'Primary' only

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you tried, but if you really tried exactly what I suggested, it would work.

Comment: select xur.UserID, r1.Name as PrimaryRoleName, r2.Name as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role xur 
JOIN Role r1
ON r1.RoleID = xur.RoleID AND SecondaryFl = 0
JOIN Role r2
ON r2.RoleID = xur.RoleID

Comment: I tried like above but got both primary and secondary values as primary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should be used

```
select xur.userId,
      max(case when SecondaryFl = 0 then r.name end) as PrimaryRoleName,
      max(case when SecondaryFl = 1 then r.name end) as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role xur 
join Role r on r.RoleID = xur.RoleID
group by xur.userId;
```

Edit by (YogeshSharma)

Always include `where` clause while doing the *conditional* aggregation as because in case  `SecondaryFl` column has more value other than above then it will include *null* rows always.

```
select xur.userId,
       max(case when SecondaryFl = 0 then r.name end) as PrimaryRoleName,
       max(case when SecondaryFl = 1 then r.name end) as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role xur 
join Role r on r.RoleID = xur.RoleID
where SecondaryFl in (1, 0) -- Always include especially for conditions aggregation 
group by xur.userId;
```

Comment: Yeah, but this query doesn't work for more than two roles. I really think this guy should rethink the result he wants.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few facts missing from the question I think. Like, what qualified a role to be seconday and primary? But for this answer I will assume that the `SecondaryFl` field indicates this. 0 for primary and 1 for secondary.

I believe that the problem you are seeing is due to this from you query:

```
JOIN Role r2
ON r2.RoleID = r1.RoleID AND SecondaryFl = 1
```

Since you are joining the Role table a second time, on the same primary key. Instead you want to join it again, but with it's own conditions.

Like this:

```
select
  user_role.UserID,
  role_primary.Name as PrimaryRoleName,
  role_secondary.Name as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role as user_role 
join Role as role_primary
  on role_primary.RoleID = user_role.RoleID and SecondaryFl = 0
join Role as role_secondary
  on role_secondary.RoleID = user_role.RoleID and SecondaryFl = 1
```

Sorry that I changed your names, I just find it more readable. It should illustrate the point clearer here I think.

EDIT: I assumed that the roles would always be present here. In case that roles are optional, you could use a `left join` instead, and handle returned nulls with something like `coalesce(role_primary.Name, 'None')` or just treat the returned null where you are receiving the results.

Like this:

```
select
  user_role.UserID,
  coalesce(role_primary.Name, 'None') as PrimaryRoleName,
  coalesce(role_secondary.Name, 'None') as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role as user_role 
left join Role as role_primary
  on role_primary.RoleID = user_role.RoleID and SecondaryFl = 0
left join Role as role_secondary
  on role_secondary.RoleID = user_role.RoleID and SecondaryFl = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot query like below
<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/PLKH18638)**</kbd>

On your note:

> I have to use JOINS because this is a part of a bigger select which is entirely made up of JOINS.

you can always encapsulate below query as a nested query in a JOIN

```
select 
    UserId,
    PrimaryRoleName=[0],
    SecondaryRoleName=[1]
from
(
    select 
        X.UserID,
        Name,
        SecondaryFl
    from 
        X_User_Role X 
    left join Role R
        on X.RoleID=R.RoleID
) src
pivot
(
    max(Name) for SecondaryFl in ([0],[1])
    )p
```

if you absolutely want a JOIN syntax, you can try below query

```
select 
    UserID=X.UserID,
    PrimaryRoleName=MAX(case when SecondaryFl=0 then Name else NULL end),
    SecondaryRoleName=MAX(case when SecondaryFl=1 then Name else NULL end)

from 
    X_User_Role X 
left join Role R
    on X.RoleID=R.RoleID
group by X.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a dynamic number of columns? You are looking for trouble.

- What if the user has three, four, five roles?

You should return the roles, one per row. A simple SQL join will do.

Comment: There are only two roles per user. He might have either primary, secondary or both.

Comment: Why do you assume OP wants a dynamic number of columns?   The question pretty clearly asks for two.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was suggesting in my comment:

```
select xur.UserID, r1.Name as PrimaryRoleName, r2.Name as SecondaryRoleName
from X_User_Role xur 
JOIN Role r1
  ON r1.RoleID = xur.RoleID AND r1.SecondaryFl <> 1
JOIN Role r2
  ON r2.RoleID = xur.RoleID AND r2.SecondaryFl = 1
WHERE xur.UserID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post another answer that doesn't resort to `GROUP BY`:

```
select x1.userid, r1.name, r2.name
  from x_user_role x1, role r1, x_user_role x2, role r2
  where r1.roleid = x1.roleid and r1.secondaryfl = 0 
    and x1.userid = 1
    and r2.roleid = x2.roleid and r2.secondaryfl = 1 
    and x2.userid = x1.userid
```